# Concatenate JS objects

Tags: javascript, object

I have two object like below

```
var data = {
        site_name: "my_site",
        page_id: "page_name",
        city: "New York",
        region_code: "NY",
        country_code: "US"
     },
     user_data = {
        user: "user_name",
        conversion_rate: 1.25
     };
```

I want to concatenate these two object like below

```
user_data = {
     user: "user_name",
     conversion_rate: 1.25,
     site_name: "my_site",
     page_id: "page_name",
     city: "New York",
     region_code: "NY",
     country_code: "US"
 };
```

I did it by looping on second on by checking `typeof user_data.key` .... and it solved my problem but my curiosity is to do it without looping in an optimized way. Any of your suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: i think jquery's extend( target [, object1 ] [, objectN ] ) is a good option

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) of ES6:

```
var combined = Object.assign({}, data, user_data);
```

Or even:

```
Object.assign(user_data, data); // this will change `user_data`
```

Comment: it is not supported by IE

Comment: @trim ES6 is not supported by IE. You have to use babel.

Comment: @trim IE only supports a very limited subset of ES6. And as Dmitri mentioned, you have to use a transpiler like [Babel](https://babeljs.io) if you need to support outdated browsers.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use Babel, simply use spread operator on objects:

```
var data = {
   site_name: "my_site",
   page_id: "page_name",
   city: "New York",
   region_code: "NY",
   country_code: "US"
},
user_data = {
   user: "user_name",
   conversion_rate: 1.25
};

var combined = {
  ...data,
  ...user_data
};

console.log(combined);
```

Please see [the demo](http://jsbin.com/lakafeh/1/edit?js,console).

"Spread properties" is still in proposal stage 2, but you can [use it with Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/).
See [here](https://rainsoft.io/why-object-literals-in-javascript-are-cool/#5alookintothefuturerestandspreadproperties) more details about this feature.

Answer (score -1):

This would work in your example case on all browsers:

```
data=JSON.stringify(data);
user_data=JSON.stringify(user_data);
user_data=user_data.replace("}",data.replace("{",","));
user_data=JSON.parse(user_data);
```